# php unset not working

Tags: php, unset

ok, not sure why this is not working

$info contains an array, there are 3 copies of user_pass that should all be removed, the first two are removed, but the third is not.

Any ideas?

```
if($phoneDetails['show_passwd'] == '0') {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($info); $i++) {
        if($info[$i]['header']['tag'] == 'user_pass') {
            unset($info[$i]);
        }elseif($info[$i]['header']['tag'] == 'http_pass') {
            unset($info[$i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the `$info` array,

Answer (score 0):

You code relies on the fact that the indices of the array go from `0` to `N-1`. Is that really your case? What if you replaced the `for` cycle with `foreach`:

```
if ($phoneDetails['show_passwd'] == '0') {
  foreach ($info as $i => $v) {  
    if ($info[$i]['header']['tag'] == 'user_pass']) {
      unset($info[$i]);
    } else if ($info[$i]['header']['tag'] == 'http_pass') {
      unset($info[$i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same code you given, but more refactored. btw I didn't get what you really need

```
if($phoneDetails['show_passwd'] == '0') { //or if(!$phoneDetails['show_passwd'])
    $i = 0;
    for($i; $i < count($info); $i++) { 
        $tag = !empty($info[$i]['header']['tag']) ? $info[$i]['header']['tag'] : '';
        if ($tag == 'user_pass' || $tag == 'http_pass') {
            unset($info[$i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: aah, might be because of  count($info) inside the for loop. $i < count($info) becomes false. use foreach like Jiri Hrazdil said